# Trig Question: Angle sum identities

Tags: trigonometry

Given that $x$ and $y$ are acute angles such that
$\frac{\sin x}{\sin y} = \frac{1}{2}$ and $\frac{\cos x}{\cos y} = \frac{3}{2}$, find $\tan (x + y).$

I got $-2$. Is that right?

Comment: HI.Welcome To MSE . can you show your work?

Comment: one helpful identity is $$\tan(x+y) = \frac{\tan(x) + \tan(y)}{1 - \tan(x)\tan(y)}$$

Comment: Yup. Here's my work. I substituted $\tan(x) = \frac{\sin(x)}{\cos(x)}$ and $\tan{y} = \frac{\sin(y)}{\cos(y)} = \frac{2\sin(x)}{2/3\cos(x)}$

Comment: Whoops, I see a mistake now.
Do I need to find $x$ and $y$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have
$$\frac{\sin x}{\sin y} = \frac{1}{2} \quad \text{i.e.} \quad 2\sin x = \sin(y) \quad \quad (1)$$
and

$$\frac{\cos x}{\cos y} = \frac{3}{2} \quad \text{i.e.} \quad 2\cos x = 3\cos(y) \quad \quad (2)$$

so $(1)^2+(2)^2$ gives
$$4=4\sin^2(x)+4\cos^2(x)=\sin^2(y)+9\cos^2(y)=1+8\cos^2(y)$$

so
$$\cos^2(y)=\frac{3}{8} \quad \text{and} \quad \sin^2(y)=\frac{5}{8}, \quad \text{so} \tan^2(y)=\frac{5}{3}$$

Now, $(1)/(2)$ gives
$$\tan(x)=\frac{\sin(y)}{3\cos(y)}=\frac{\tan(y)}{3}$$

You deduce that
$$\tan(x+y)=\frac{\tan(x) + \tan(y)}{1 - \tan(x)\tan(y)} = \frac{4\tan(y)}{3 - \tan^2(y)} = 3\tan(y) =\sqrt{15}$$

because $x$ and $y$ are acute angles.

Answer (score 1):

We have that

$$\frac{\cos x}{\cos y} = \frac{3}{2} \implies \frac{1-\sin^2 x}{1-\sin^2 y}=\frac94 \implies 9 \sin^2y-4\sin^2 x=5$$

and by $\frac{\sin x}{\sin y} = \frac{1}{2}$

$$9 \sin^2y-4\sin^2 x=5 \implies 8\sin^2 y=5 \implies \sin y=\sqrt{\frac58} \quad \sin x=\frac12\sqrt{\frac58}$$

and then

$$ \cos y=\sqrt{\frac38} \quad \cos x=\frac32\sqrt{\frac38}$$

finally we can use that

$$\tan(x+y)= \frac{\sin x \cos y+\sin y \cos x}{\cos x \cos y-\sin x \sin y}=\frac{\frac1{16}\sqrt{15}+\frac3{16}\sqrt{15}}{\frac9{16}-\frac5{16}}=\sqrt{15}$$